# Prove (without derivatives) that for any $b\in \mathbb{R}$, $b>1$, that $ b^x >1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am trying to prove (without using any differential calculus) that $b^x > 1$ for $b\in \mathbb{R}$, $b>1$ and $x \in\mathbb{R}$ for $x>0$. I was wondering if anyone had any hints on how to do this.

Comment: One simple way is first to find where $b^x=1$. By taking a logarithm you find the only solution is $x=0$ which is outside of the domain you have. At the same time for $x=1$ you have $b^x=b>1$. So at least for one $x$, $b^x>1$. But then by continuity (do you know that $b^x$ is continuous?), it can never become negative in $x>0$, since that requires $b^x$ becoming equal to one at some point.

Comment: This depends on how you defined $b^x$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that exponential and the logarithm are strictly increasing functions. $b^x =exp(xln(b))$ since $b>1$, $ln(b)>0$ and $xln(b)>0$ use that exponential is strictly increasing to conclude that $b^x=exp(xln(b))>exp(0)=1$.